# A fuller story of up/down-voting

Tags: discussion, votes

MO-participants should appreciate the difference between information about  **+1** vote   and   **+4 vs -3** votes.   This is especially the case of closed questions.

I hope that MO will implement the more complete way.

Comment: @Glorfindel, thank you for fixing my typos (twice from OM to MO).

Comment: A related post on [meta.se]: [Please reduce or eliminate the reputation required to see the upvote/downvote vote split](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72743). On [math.meta.se]: [Why can only established users view vote counts?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9659)

Answer (score 18):

This is already possible for users with [1,000 or more reputation](https://mathoverflow.net/help/privileges/established-user):

> #### How do I view vote counts?
>
> Voting scores, as displayed, are the sum of the up and down votes on a post. Vote counts are the individual up and down votes that make up the score.
>
> You can view the vote counts by clicking on the score of a post. This will break the score into upvotes and downvotes, like so:
>
> [image]

Whether that privilege should be available for users with less reputation as well is an [eternal debate on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/69852?lq=1).

Comment: The format as **+4 vs -3** should be presented **directly** to participants without bothering participants to make another click (many don't even know about the option).

Comment: Yes, that is what many users have been proposing but (so far) to no avail.