# Is there a way to see the up/down vote spread on all questions asked by a given user?

Tags: discussion, statistics, voting, data-explorer

When you as a user get some sufficiently high reputation, [you can see](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/4899/11540) the up/down vote spread of any question/answer. Now suppose there's some user, X, you're interested in. On their page you can sort their questions (or answers) by score (= upvotes - downvotes). You can also do this using the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/942475/answers-of-a-deleted-user).

Here's my question: can I run a query like that, but see the number of upvotes and the number of downvotes instead of just the score?

This would save me from having to go and open every one of X's questions, then click the score, and jot down the up/downvote count. The reason I ask is that I was recently having a discussion with another long time user and had an example in mind of a user who had a ton of both upvotes and downvotes, but it was a bit difficult to find examples of contributions by that user to serve as the example.

Comment: I changed the title, since as it was, it seemed to me ambiguous between what you intended, and asking to see a single users up/down votes across all questions they'd voted on. The first thing I thought of on reading the title was the latter. Clearly nuances like there not being a comma in a certain place means that it probably wasn't technically ambiguous, but more clarity doesn't hurt! :-)

Comment: @DavidRoberts Ok, great, thanks! More clarity is always welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SEDE](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/data-explorer/info) contains the table Votes which can be used for this, see also: [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677).

- Here is an example of such query - you can change userid to switch to another user and choose whether you want to see [only questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1816563/posts-answers-questions-of-a-given-user-with-the-number-of-upvotes-and-downvote?userid=11540&types=1), [only answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1816563/posts-answers-questions-of-a-given-user-with-the-number-of-upvotes-and-downvote?userid=11540&types=2) or [both](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1816563/posts-answers-questions-of-a-given-user-with-the-number-of-upvotes-and-downvote?userid=11540&types=1,2). (Naturally you can run the same query on other sites, too. If you try some site different from MO or meta.MO, do not forget that your userid on that site is different.)
- In your question you have linked to an example of a query for a *deleted user* - if this is what your interested in you can try a query [like this](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1816564/posts-answers-questions-of-a-deleted-user-with-the-number-of-upvotes-and-downvo?userid=9072).
- You can easily get a query looking at [anonymous feedback](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1816565/posts-answers-questions-of-a-given-user-with-the-upvotes-and-downvotes-from-ano?userid=11540) rather than votes from users with [sufficient reputation to vote](https://mathoverflow.net/help/privileges/vote-up). For more info on anonymous feedback, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/post-feedback/info).

Keep in mind that the data in SEDE is updated only once a week.

You mentioned in the question that you're looking into some users who have both many upvotes and many downvotes - here is a query listing users together with the number of upvotes and downvotes on their posts.
Again, you can choose whether to count [all posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1816639/users-and-upvotes-downvotes-on-their-posts-questions-answers?types=1,2),
[only questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1816639/users-and-upvotes-downvotes-on-their-posts-questions-answers?types=1) or
[only answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1816639/users-and-upvotes-downvotes-on-their-posts-questions-answers?types=2).

If you want to look at some posts that have both many upvotes you can have a look at this question from Mathematics Meta: [Which posts have a high value of $\min(\text{upvotes, downvotes})$?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34567) Here is a [modification of a query I posted there](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1816663/posts-with-the-highest-minupvotes-downvotes-with-information-about-the-post?num=500&types=1,2) which also shows some additional information about the post.

---

Unrelated to the original question - several questions which can be answered with a SEDE query have been asked recently. (Here are the graphs showing number of posts tagged [statistics](/questions/tagged/statistics) [per month](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.mathoverflow/query/1073716/number-of-questions-in-a-given-tag-per-month?tagname=statistics#graph) and  [per year](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.mathoverflow/query/1672251/number-of-questions-in-a-given-tag-per-year?tagname=statistics#graph).)
At least for some of those questions, the answers weren't difficult and probably anybody having some experience with SEDE and SQL would be able to answer them,
I will point out that there are two chat rooms dedicated specifically to SEDE: [Data Explorer (SEDE)](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/1223/data-explorer-sede) (on MSE Chat) or [SEDE - Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/13526/sede-stack-exchange-data-explorer) (on SE Chat). I think that [the main MathOverflow chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9369) would be a reasonable place to ask about things like this, too. And you could contact me [in my chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/19138/martin-sleziaks-room) if needed - depending on how busy I am, I might at least try to answer. (I should add a caveat that my knowledge of SQL is rather limited - what I know I have learned from the queries I have seen in various discussions here on Stack Exchange.)